# react-native equivalent for inputElement.setSelectionRange?

Tags: forms, react-native

Is there a way to manipulate the cursor within text inputs? I'm looking for the functional equivalent of the web's `input.setSelectionRange(start, end)` (a la https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange)

I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-textinput-utils, but it seems pretty hokey. Is this all that's available?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any solid APIs exposed for managing selection state in the core TextInput at the moment. The library you linked to above might be your only bet.